# How to set a pointer to struct to NULL in C?

Tags: c, null

I have an array of pointer to struct, and for any reasons when I print this array, there is a spare element at the end of it, and thus causes the code to print a NULL byte at the end.

Is there anyway I can delete the last chunk of memory?

***For example:***

```
typedef struct
{
    char *name;
} B;

typedef struct
{
    B *var;
} A;

int main() {
    int num = 5; //for example
    A *foo = malloc(sizeof(A));
    B *bar = malloc(num * sizeof(B));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        bar[i] = *create_b(&bar[i]); // some function that works.
    }
    foo->var = bar;
    while (foo->var != NULL) {
        printf("This is %s\n",foo->var->name);
            foo->var++; 
    }
}
```

Everything is printed out just fine, but there's an unwanted printing at the end of the loop. Something like:

```
This is A
This is B
This is C
This is D
This is F
This is
```

Apparently the array only has 5 elements, the last one prints nothing.

Comment: Check whether the array is null terminated or not if it is a char array as a member of struct. It is not supposed to print it. It's difficult to figure out unless you show us the code what you are actually trying.

Comment: have you initialized the data in the array ?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code in question? Like how you define the array, the struct, and how you print the array?

Comment: Are you sure you are iterating over the `right amount` of elements that array of pointers has?

Comment: I just added the code :)

Comment: The question and this example snippet are both too confusing. You would be better off posting the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your printing loop is:

```
foo->var = bar;
while (foo->var != NULL) {
    printf("This is %s\n",foo->var->name);
    foo->var++; 
}
```

But `foo->var` will never equal NULL, since you're just incrementing a pointer, so you will eventually read past the end of the `bar` array and your application will probably crash.

If you replace the `while` loop with `for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)`, it will print the correct number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `foo->var++`, because there is no place in the array that is set to `NULL`. Also, using that `++` changes `foo->var` so after the loop `foo->var` no longer points at the start of the array, and you can not access the array again.

You need to allocate memory for some end-of-array marker, just like strings has the character `\0` to mark the end of the string.

Try the following:

```
int main() {
    int num = 5; //for example
    A *foo = malloc(sizeof(A));
    B *bar = malloc((num + 1) * sizeof(B));  // +1 for array terminator
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        bar[i] = *create_b(&bar[i]); // some function that works.
    }
    bar[i].name = NULL;  // Use this as a marker to mean end of array
    foo->var = bar;
    for (B *tmp = foo->var; tmp->name != NULL; tmp++) {
        printf("This is %s\n",tmp->name);
    }
}
```

**Edit** Had some errors in the code.

Answer (score -1):

<del>Your problem is probably in the function create_b, which you did not post.</del>

Edit: no, that's probably wrong, sorry.

But surely this isn't what you want:

```
bar[i] = *create_b(&bar[i]);
```

You both pass in the address of bar[i] and set it equal to whatever the return value points to?

Comment: It only sets a name for 'bar', which prints out ok as you see. But the loop only goes from 0 to num?